# Spring JS - input field

Tags: javascript, spring, eclipse, hibernate, jsp

I have two input fields in a .jsp file, both are visible at the same time. phone1 is mandatory and is working as intended (must be filled in, length of 10, following a format). However phone2 is not working; I would like phone2 to follow the same rules as phone1 but to only notify a problem if something was entered in the input field.

ex. if a letter or only one number was entered into phone2, set element text to:

"*please enter a 10 digit number with no special characters"

```
    var phoneformat = /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/;

      //phone1="home phone" phone2="work phone"

      if (phone1 == "" || phone1.length != 10 || !phone1.match(phoneformat)){
        document.getElementById("vHphone").innerHTML="*please enter a 10 digit number with no special characters";
        return false;
    } else if (phone2 != "" && phone2.length < 10 || !phone2.match(phoneformat)){
        document.getElementById("vWphone").innerHTML="*please enter a 10 digit number with no special characters";
        return false;
```

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Downvoted because it seems like OP is slapping as many unrelated tags on his question as he can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just try adding `phone2 != ""` to the right of the current `or` operator too. Otherwise, it is triggered just for `!phone2.match(phoneformat)`.

```
else if (phone2 != "" && phone2.length < 10 || phone2 != "" && !phone2.match(phoneformat))
```

Or

```
else if(phone2 != ""){
  if(phone2.length < 10 || !phone2.match(phoneformat)){
     return false;
  }
}
```